# I want to shift the value in a column for a particular row and shift the other rows one down in the column ?

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, Item and Rank

```
a <- data.frame(item=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'),rank=1:26)
```

I want to change the rank of the item 't' whose current rank is 20 to rank 10 and shift the item whose current rank is 10 i.e 'j' by one rank down and so it gets the new rank 11 and so on with for the rest of the data frame with 's' getting the new rank 20
The data frame would look something like this

```
b <- data.frame(item=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','t','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','u','v','w','x','y','z'),rank=1:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which ranks you will change you can use a function like this, while `x` is the data.frame, `y` the rank of the value you want to change and `z` the target rank.

```
foo <- function(x, y, z){ 
          x$rank[c(z, y)] <- c(z+0.1, z) # specify the new ranks
          x <- x[order(x$rank),] # order
          x$rank <- 1:nrow(x) # update the rank
          x}
foo(a, 20, 10) 
   item rank
1     a    1
2     b    2
3     c    3
4     d    4
5     e    5
6     f    6
7     g    7
8     h    8
9     i    9
20    t   10
10    j   11
11    k   12
12    l   13
13    m   14
14    n   15
15    o   16
16    p   17
17    q   18
18    r   19
19    s   20
21    u   21
22    v   22
23    w   23
24    x   24
25    y   25
26    z   26
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the job, bear in mind it works only if you lower the rank:

```
rank_ini <- a$rank[a$item == "t"]
new_rank <- 10

to_be_shifted <- a$rank %in% (new_rank:(rank_ini-1))
a$rank[to_be_shifted] <- a$rank[to_be_shifted] + 1
a$rank[a$item == "t"] <- new_rank

a <- a[order(a$rank),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do a circular shift on items 10 through 20 without the need to re-rank the data. That is:

```
v <- a$item[10:20]
a$item[10:20] <- c(tail(v, 1),head(v, -1))
```

**data**

```
a <- data.frame(item=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'),rank=1:26, stringsAsFactors = F)
```